# Add New Parameter to Existing URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a url like below

```
http://filespecification.phpnet.us/index3.php
```

But i want to add an additional parameter to this url like below.

```
http://filespecification.phpnet.us/index3.php?email=
```

For this i am using `.htaccess` to redirect with additional parameter but it is not redirecting still show original url.

`RewriteRule /index3.php$ index3.php?email=$1 [R]`

But it is not working. How can i redirect with additional parameter?

Comment: What is the value of `email` you are expecting?

Comment: `$1` is not defined

Comment: Remove the leading slash from your Rule's pattern.

Comment: any value can be added to this by writing manually in url.

Comment: @starkeen when change the rule to this `RewriteRule index3.php$ index3.php?email=$1 [R]` then it redirect to this url. `http://filespecification.phpnet.us/here is it shows complete patha like Public_html /index3.php?page=`

Comment: See my answer bellow. You also need to add a leading slash to the destination path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple one. Hope this will be helpful. I have tested it.

> **1.** `QUERY_STRING` does not contain email.
>
> **2.** if request uri is `index3.php` redirect to `/index3.php?email=somevalue`

**Flags:**

> `R` for redirection.
>
> `L` last redirection.
>
> `QSA` query string append

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!email)
RewriteRule index3.php$ /index3.php?email=somevalue [L,R,QSA]
```

You can check this `.htaccess` code here http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: it works, can you please explain, what is function of first line? `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Comment: nicely understand you, but now i change my your rule to this `RewriteRule .*$ /index.php?email= [L,R]` means when someone visit `http://filespecification.phpnet.us` it redirects to `http://filespecification.phpnet.us/index.php?email=` but all images are not showing.

Comment: I got the issue, on your website you have `img/Offices.png` which is the link of your image, i cant be accessed because you have redirected all requests to `index.php`

Comment: @HamzaZafeer You will get to know the issue, if you try to open this link http://filespecification.phpnet.us/img/Offices.png Can you explain in brief what you are trying to do.

Comment: got it, how  can i overcome this? This solution give me a new problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147225/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-hamza-zafeer).

Answer (score 0):

Your rule isn't working due to the leading slash. You need to remove it.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\?email= [NC]
RewriteRule index3.php$ /index3.php?email=mail [L,R]
```

Comment: it redirects, but browser says *This page isn’t working

filespecification.phpnet.us redirected you too many times.*

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the condition to check empty querystring. Fixed.